# Simple code for Half-Sine function

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to write a simple piece of code to define a half-sine pulse of a vibration shaker, to later transform into a shock response. I'm just trying to define a Sine function inside an interval, and outside that interval the function needs to be Zero:

```
Time = np.linspace(0,0.01,110)
Amplitude = 70
Period = 0.002
Function = 0.0

if Time.all() <= Period:
    Function = Amplitude * np.sin(np.pi * Time/Period) 
else:
    Function = 0.0
```

The problem is that it looks that Python ignores the if statement, and plots me a full Sine function until for all the values of Time.

I'm sorry if this is a very newbie question, but I cannot find a solution to this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: check `print(Time.all())`. What do you expect to be the outcome of `False <= 0.002`? And please post a short example of what you want your result to look like. Besides that `x` is not an operator in python!

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not, please specify the problem and I'll try to help. If yes, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the valuable help! I'm quite new in Python and I'm used to ROOT, which is C++...I can see how Python is much better in scientific programming. Many thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. I m coming from C and Matlab. Python is much more comfortable to use for scientific programming. And if you use Python correctly, performance shouldn't be a problem. I guess that these are the reasons for Python's popularity for scientific programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `Time.all()` is `False`, how do you want to compare it with `<= 0.002`? You either need to loop over your arrays (not recommended) or use a boolean index mask to apply zeros to your `Function`:

```
Time = np.linspace(0, 0.01, 110)
Amplitude = 70
Period = 0.002
Function = 0.0

Function = Amplitude * np.sin(np.pi * Time / Period)
# apply setting to zero where the boolean mask is True
# the boolean mask is True, where the condition Time > Period is True
Function[Time > Period] = 0.
```

Besides that there are a few more "stylistic" issues in your code. According to [PEP8 styleguide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?), only classes should start with uppercases. Variables should always be lowercase. This is the reason for your (probably) quite strange code colouring in your IDE.

Comment: That helped me a lot! Many thanks to all the answers :-)